# Scrapy Regex grab date based on format?

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to grab the date out of this block of code. the issue I am having is some lines in the table have an image and some do not. if the image is present the date is in the alt text, if its not then its just the paragraph text.

```html
'<p class="b-fight-details__table-text">\n          \n          Jul. 06, 2018\n        </p>',

or 

'<p class="b-fight-details__table-text">\n          \n              <img src="http://1e49bc5171d173577ecd-1323f4090557a33db01577564f60846c.r80.cf1.rackcdn.com/belt.png" alt="">\n          \n          Oct. 05, 2019\n        </p>'
```

```html
            'Fight_Date':
                    fight_url.xpath('.//td[6]/p[2]').extract_first().strip() if fight_url.xpath('.//td[1]/p/a/i/i/text()').extract_first().strip() == "next"
                    else fight_url.xpath('.//td[7]/p[2]').extract_first().strip(),
```

Comment: Can you give us a more complete block of html, in the examples you've given the date looks to be inside the `<p>` tag in both? Also please check your code, it certainly can't just start with `'Flight_Date':`?

Comment: correct the date is inside the <p> tag in both. however when the image is present the date is in the alt text of the image and when its not present its the text of the paragraph. if I add "/text()" to the end of the xpath it pulls the date as long as the image is not there.

Comment: Just get all the text with `.getall()` and go from there?

Answer (score 0):

The example does not meet the description (no date in `alt`).
In any case, a solution for you would be to use CSS selectors for both cases you mentioned, separating them by a comma. Eg.

```
response.css('.b-fight-details__table-text::text,.b-fight-details__table-text img::attr(alt)').getall()
```